# Not able to click a link which is part of business details container listed on home page using JavaScript in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

There are multiple businesses listed on a home page and some business names may have the same name. I have to click on the link 'Apply for Business Credit' and it would navigate to a different screen. I have tried multiple solutions but not able to click on desired link. Please have a look on the home screen
[image]

I have also added html for your reference.
[image]

Solutions I have tried -

```
    cy.get('div.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-item').contains('Shemaroo Equities').eq(0)
    .nextUntil('div')
    .contains('p','Apply for Business Credit')
    .click({force:true})

    cy.get('div.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-item').contains('Shemaroo Equities').eq(0).nextUntil('div button span.MuiTouchRipple-root').click()
```

I am relatively new to cypress. I request the community to help me resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Does your page always have duplicate business names? How do you know you are selecting the correct business if there are duplicates?

Comment: It can have duplicate names as one business can request for multiple loans. So for automation purposes I already said I am clicking the link for first entry.

Answer (score 0):

//Try below code to click on the first instance of "Shemaroo Equities"

```
 cy.contains('ShemarooEquities')
.eq(0).parent().siblings().eq(1).within(()=>{
cy.contains('Apply for Business Credit').click()
})
```

or

```
cy.contains('ShemarooEquities')
    .eq(0).parent().next().next().within(()=>{
    cy.contains('Apply for Business Credit').click()
    })
```

or

```
cy.contains('ShemarooEquities')
    .eq(0).parent().parent().within(()=>{
    cy.contains('Apply for Business Credit').click()
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for time and efforts but it did not work.

Comment: May i know what error you exactly see in cypress...May be a screenshot will help

Comment: I am getting the following error "Timed out retrying after 9000 ms: expected to find content: 'Apply for Business Credit' but never did."

Comment: I am not sure which element exactly holds the content 'Shemaroo Equities' from your html reference. Only if you share the html reference of element that holds the text 'Shemaroo Equities' and then the associated button element within it. we can sort out a way.

Comment: I just added another print screen for html and highlighting the element to provide more info. Thanks @Priya for your time and efforts.

Comment: Hi, I updated the code based on your screenshot. Try those options.

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite simple to get the first instance of a business card by using `cy.contains('selector', 'text')` with an added chained `.contains()` to get the 'Apply for Business Credit' link.

```js
// yields the first card with Shemaroo Equities
cy.contains('.MuiGrid-container', 'Shemaroo Equities')
  .should('be.visible')
  // chained queries are limited to previous subject
  .contains('Apply for Business Credit')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your time & efforts @jjhelguero . It is able to identify the element properly but  not able to click it. I also tried it with modification click({force:true}) but did not work.